# Text on top of image Fancybox

Tags: fancybox-3

I use Fancybox3 to display some images and I want to place a text on top of an image. This works when i edit the javascript file with this:

test

With this I have text on the actual image. But this text is big when Fancybox zooms the image in and out. Why is this happening and is there a way to solve this?

I want a simple image download text on the image instead of below the image.

Comment: In my post above I published a code line. Something went wrong. This is what I meant: `<div class="fancybox-image-wrap"><span class="test">test</span></div>` instead of just 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fancybox-is-scaling` class name to hide your text while image is zooming, similarly to this demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/ePYNZo.

The script uses CSS `transform: scale()` for zooming to improve performance, but the side-effect is that everything scales withing the container.

Comment: Where to add this class? Tried it in the earlier mentioned span and that doesn't work. The text is still big when zooming in and out. I also couldn't find this class in the example on codepen. I did found it in the css file I have.

Comment: If you do not know where to put CSS and you are not able to spot CSS class that is literally in the middle of the screen, then, sorry, I give up.

Comment: I know where it is in the example. But the example css says `.fancybox-is-scaling .fancybox-image` and I don't see both in the example html or Javascript. I even can't find it in the source code. There is an example, I only don't know how it exactly works. Sorry, but I'm not as educated as you are when it comes to coding such things.

Comment: If you would have created a codepen demo, I would be able to help in no time https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve